# Using render :inline but still getting ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

How come I still getting this error? shouldn't render :inline removes the need for a template?

Thanks

Comment: Is your `render :inline` getting executed at all ?

Comment: You can as well use `render :text => "Something"`

Comment: well, if its not getting executed then how would it come in action ??

Comment: My bad, there was a if statement that skipped the render, thanks Pamio!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the controller:

```
render :inline => "OK", :layout => "application"
```

if you don't put the :layout => "application", no layout template will be used.

Comment: But I still want to return some text like render :inline => "OK"